# Best practice for indexing foreign keys on a large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, clustered-index

I have a large table (SQL Server 2008) with almost 3 million rows.  It currently has a clustered index on it's primary key, and a non-clustered index on its foreign key.

Almost all the queries on the table are reads based on the foreign key.

1. Should I change the index on the table to be against the foreign key?
2. What is the best process for doing this?

Thanks

Comment: How many values are in the FK column?  There's little benefit in changing the index depending on how many - IE: two would be worthless to index.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but are you asking how many potential FK values are there?  If so, around 16,000....

Comment: @OMGPonies, wouldn't setting the clustered index on the foreign key values help his SQL queries?  His query would be faster because it wouldn't have to do a bookmark lookup for the data of the row.

Comment: @Micky McQuade - that was my understanding, problem is the table is so large that it's quite difficult to make any structural changes to it....

Comment: @Micky McQuade: If `SELECT DISTINCT fk_column FROM YOUR_TABLE` returns *few values*, an index (clustered or not) won't help.  Because there's not enough to distinguish between records. Potential values doesn't matter.

Comment: Got it - that returns over 10,000 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more about your situation, I think that changing the non-clustered index to be a non-clustered, covering index would be the best solution.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/